# Crawler4j cannot AJAX Crawling

Tags: java, web-crawler, crawler4j

I am trying to download data from the ajax based websites. But crawler4j doesn't support ajax crawling. I want to use crawler4j but with this functionality. My project is based on crawler4j. I there is any way to do please share link and snippet.

Answer (score 3):

Check [this](https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j/pull/82) pull-request by MadEgg - maybe this will solve your issue. You can also refer to [the related issue](https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j/issues/97) on the project page to emphasize the need for AJAX crawling within the `crawler4j` framework.